# Would refrigeration lengthen shelf life for this water sweetener?

Tags: food-science, chemistry

Ingredients: vegetable glycerin, purified water, citric acid, malic acid, natural flavor, stevia leaf extract, sodium citrate.

Container is about 2-3 ounces.

It says on the container: "Does not need refrigeration. For best quality use within 30 days from opening. Store in a cool dry place."

Would such a recipe spoil after thirty days?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely answer here is that the flavor compounds either degrade (oxidize) or evaporate over time in an opened container. Refrigeration is unlikely to change this a lot as the rate of evaporation is dependent on the diffusion gradient A large gradient = faster diffusion, which would be determined by the head-space in the opened bottle.

Oxidation processes are dependent on the amount of substance to be oxidized and the amount of available oxygen, though there also things like free-radicals which can oxidize one molecule and then move on to the next. Temperature might slow this a little, but probably not so much that you would notice greatly.